# How can I connect H2 database as embedded mode on Android platform by using Gluon?

Tags: h2, gluon

I want to use H2 database to store database on my Gluon Mobile application. I have try JDBC it work well on Desktop version. but I got failed on Android (org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file).

I have change connection like the following url, but not luck
http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

**Edited to Add gradle**

**My Code**

```
try {
            Connection connection=null;

            lbError.setText("");
            lbError.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Label="+ label.getText());
            //step1 load the driver class
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER).newInstance();
            //step2 create  the connection object

             if(Platform.isDesktop())
                 connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
             if(Platform.isAndroid())
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION_ANDROID,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

            System.out.print("DATABASE Create");
            //step3 create the statement object
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;\n" +
                        "CREATE TABLE contact(\n" +
                        "        Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +
                        "        Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "        Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n" +
                        "        PRIMARY KEY (ID)\n" +
                        ");";
            System.out.println("SQL="+"\n"+sql);

            //step4 execute query
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Table Created");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error Line is here");
            lbError.setText(e.toString());
            lbError.setVisible(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
07-10 10:30:38.770 30397 30435 W System.err: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file "/data/data/com.khmerdev.views" [90062-196]
07-10 10:30:38.771 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:274)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory(FileUtils.java:42)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:309)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:308)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:74)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2476)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:697)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:276)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:270)
07-10 10:30:38.772 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.khmerdev.views.ContactPresenter.initDB(ContactPresenter.java:75)
07-10 10:30:38.773 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.khmerdev.views.ContactPresenter.initialize(ContactPresenter.java:53)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:277)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.khmerdev.views.ContactView.getView(ContactView.java:11)
07-10 10:30:38.774 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.khmerdev.GluonApplication.lambda$init$0(GluonApplication.java:19)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.khmerdev.GluonApplication$$Lambda$1.get(GluonApplication.java)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.a.a.a(SourceFile:1032)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:721)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(SourceFile:475)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(SourceFile:450)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:266)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:232)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(LauncherImpl.java)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(PlatformImpl.java)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
07-10 10:30:38.775 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
07-10 10:30:38.776 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)
07-10 10:30:38.776 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
07-10 10:30:38.777 30397 30435 W System.err:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:57)
07-10 10:30:38.777 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
07-10 10:30:38.777 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)
07-10 10:30:38.778 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
07-10 10:30:38.778 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
07-10 10:30:38.778 30397 30435 W System.err:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
07-10 10:30:38.778 30397 30435 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

**Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.khmerdev.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile files('libs/h2-1.4.196.jar')
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.khmerdev.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the build.gradle with the dependencies of your project?

Comment: Okay, I will do it

Comment: Have you tried the [Gluon-sqlite](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/gluon-SQLite) sample? If you replace the driver to `org.h2.Driver` and connection to `jdbc:h2:` it should work (with the proper h2 syntax of course).

Comment: @JoséPereda: So you mean that I have to follow the sample code of Gluon-sqlite and just change driver and connection?

Comment: I will try it, I will let you know the result

Comment: @JoséPereda: I got problem on iOS about driver. Do you know how to fixed it with H2?

Comment: @JoséPereda: Check also check the discussion in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301624/gluon-application-cant-load-fxml-on-ios-when-i-using-h2-database-as-embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to José Pereda that give me some idea, Now I found the solution of the above problem. we need to get the correct private storage first by the following code:

```
File dir = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                    .map(s -> s.getPrivateStorage().get())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("Error: PrivateStorage not available"));
```

The out put of the code above should be  `/data/user/0/com.khmerdev/files`. Then we need to use this directory to concatenate with dbUrl. See the following example below:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:/data/user/0/com.khmerdev/files" +
    "/test" +
    ";FILE_LOCK=FS" +
    ";PAGE_SIZE=1024" +
    ";CACHE_SIZE=8192";
```

In the example above "test" is the sample database name. So we need to use this string url with JDBC in order to making database transaction.